# AngularJS: show other div and hide current div on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<div>` which contains a `<button>`. When this button is clicked, I want this `<div>` to be hidden and another new `<div>` to be shown in place of the current `<div>`. Also, the new `<div>` contains a `<button>`, which when clicked opens the old `<div>`. This will enable me to open one `<div>` at a time on click of the `<button>` present in those `<div>`. Can anyone tell me how to do this in AngularJS?

[This picture shows my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMjA9.jpg)

Comment: What did you tried ? plnkrr or fiddle

Comment: What do u mean `in place of the current`?Are you want to replace or want to do hide-show?

Comment: Image link is not present

Comment: @R.J Yes, I want to hide-show. Image link is http://i.stack.imgur.com/fMjA9.jpg

Comment: 403 forbidden access :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body ng-init="showDiv = true">  

  <div ng-show="showDiv">
       <h1>Div 1</h1>
       <button ng-click="showDiv = false">Show Div 2</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="showDiv">
        <h1>Div 2</h1>
       <button ng-click="showDiv = true">Show Div 1</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/RaymondAtivie/pen/OXYRyE

Comment: Div 1 hides, but Div 2 does not appear on click of "Show Div 2" button. Can you show me the working example?

Comment: @k-Infected i did an edit try it. while i work on a code pen

Answer (score 0):

Please try something similar to below: use ng-click and ng-show

```
<div ng-show="!showDiv">
        <button ng-click="showDiv=true"></button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showDiv">
    <button ng-click="showDiv=false"></button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ngShow`:

```
<div ng-show="condition" ng-init="condition = true">
    <button ng-click="condition = false">Toggle</button>
</div>
 <div ng-show="!condition">
    <button ng-click="condition = true">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

But keep in mind to seperate logic like the toggle in `ngClick` from the view and put it in the controller.